# Inline install doesn't work on new extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Does anybody have the same problem? New extension with verified domain and enabled inline install after clicking on button with `chrome.webstore.install();`cause redirect to chromestore with get parameter `?utm_source=inline-install-disabled`

Comment: Usually, that happens due to "deceiving and deceptive content" which Google deems as misleading for the users. However, I heard of an issue going on as of recently, but not sure how widespread it is, here is an old article on what I said above. https://venturebeat.com/2015/08/06/google-will-disable-deceptive-inline-installation-of-chrome-extensions-on-september-3/

Answer (score 0):

I recently received the following email from Chrome Web Store Developer Support:

> In addition to the existing extension-level protection, our expanded
>   enforcement will also use machine learning to evaluate each inline
>   installation request for signals of deceptive, confusing, or malicious
>   ads or webpages. When we find those signals, we'll selectively disable
>   that one inline installation request and redirect the user to the
>   extension's page on the Chrome Web Store. This selective enforcement
>   will not impact inline installation of that extension from other,
>   non-deceptive sources. Developers will not be notified of this
>   enforcement, as it happens on an as-needed basis.

Are you serving any ads on your site or doing anything else that might be perceived as a grey area by ML?

If you're being blatantly deceptive, it would appear that you've been found out. If not, and you're genuinely confused, a possible first step would be to scrape your site of any ads or injected content altogether to see if you're able to regain Google's trust.